# How to create contentversion by using file url?

Tags: apex, attachment, files, contentversion

We want to create ContentVersion related to the account object. We have one field on account which contains the URL of the file(png/jpg/pdf). And by using that URL we want to create ContentVersion. But we are not getting how to get the body of that file to pass the ContentVersion's versiondata parameter. So we have used HTTP callouts. But response is coming null. Below is the code

```
Http h = new Http(); 
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest(); 
req.setEndpoint(Url); 
req.setMethod('GET'); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf'); 
req.setCompressed(true); 
req.setTimeout(60000);
HttpResponse res  = h.send(req); 
blob retFile = res.getBodyAsBlob();
ContentVersion conVer = new ContentVersion();
conVer.ContentLocation = 'S';
conVer.PathOnClient = Url+'.png';
conVer.IsMajorVersion = true;
conVer.versionData = retFile;
insert conVer;

Id conDoc = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id =:conVer.Id].ContentDocumentId;
ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = New ContentDocumentLink();
conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = accid;
conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = conDoc;
conDocLink.shareType = 'V';
conDocLink.Visibility='AllUsers';
insert conDocLink;
```

Can you please help us to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you share a sample URL?

Comment: (1) do you get back a statuscode of 200? (2) you're getting a PDF and then making the ContentVersion as a png?

Comment: @Harout Tatarian
Url example - 'https://DomainName.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/030000008kwa/a/03000000DDj4/zqkmXhjfjbPzgGayolQ_3A3Xqg0K16Opb3jg1u9ogH0'

Comment: @cropredy
Yes we are getting 200 status code & We have tried PNG also instead of PDF but the issue is same

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works well for me (little change on line 12, I remove the '.png')

Be sure you add the file source in "Setup - > Remote Site Settings"